# When making a storybook like application in Xcode would hard coding or using the Interface Builder be more efficient?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm about to start making this type of application and have a bunch of the graphics ready.

I was just wondering if it's easier to implement the graphics and changing the text would be easier/more efficient in hard coding or using the Interface Builder.

If so what's the best ways to put in the graphics and change text in whichever the better option?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with Interface Builder and learn how to link IBOutlets and actions to your code. It will make it easier for you go get started, you will be able to change things faster and collaborate with designers.

Keep in mind that there is a place for both approches, but if you *can* use the interface builder, you probably *should* use it. :D